# Click on reCAPTCHA v2 element with Python + Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, recaptcha

I want to automate the clicking of the Captcha checkbox using Python3 + Selenium, for the following [website](https://www.consularappointment.sg/ConsularAppointment).

[reCAPTCHA Checkbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5TX.png)

I tried with the below code for that

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/div[1]').click()
```

It gave No Such Element error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/div[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.79)
```

I really appreciate it if you can advise me something.

Answer (score 0):

That checkbox is in an iframe. This is one way to interact with it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://www.consularappointment.sg/ConsularAppointment'
browser.get(url) 
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='reCAPTCHA']")))
t.sleep(2) 
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click()
print('clicked')
### do other stuff in the iframe, and when you want to access other elements from the actual page
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Selenium docs can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Now it shows me the additional steps to select images. Is there anyway to automate this as well?